# ¿Como crear base de datos y despues consultarlos en excel a traves de python?

Tags: python, base-de-datos, array, lista, python-2.x

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un programa en el que pueda agregar datos en un archivo de excel y posteriormente consultarlos, para ello debo utilizar las librerias openpyxl (para manejo del archivo .xlsx) y tkinter (para la ventana en donde se deben ingresar los datos), mi problema es que no se como indicar que los datos se vayan guardando en en cada fila y no se sobreescriban y como consultarlos. Los dato son (nombre, sexo, edad, telefono) estos se deben de guardar cada uno en una columna.

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio Bay, te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas buenas respuestas. También, aprovecha y realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla.

Comment: Bay tu pregunta es muy vaga. ¿Que quieres decir con "en una ventana", usar  la terminal una o interfaz gráfica?¿Si es esto último, con qué framework? ¿Que datos se ingresarían?¿Que biblioteca usas para manejar el archivo excel (Pandas, openpyxl, xlwings, etc)? ¿O acaso es en realidad un archivo CSV?¿Has intentado algo? Si es así agrégalo a la pregunta para que podamos basarnos en algo. Por desgracia la pregunta tal y como está es demasiado amplia e imprecisa, editala a ver si podemos ayudar. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla es almacenar los datos en texto plano como fichero csv ([Comma separated value](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valores_separados_por_comas))

Los software como Excel o Libreoffice Calc no tienen problemas al abrir dichos archivos e importarlos en su hoja de calculo

```
import csv
outFile = open('fichero.csv','wb')
writer = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')
writer.writerow['columna1', 'columna2', 'columna3']

outFile.close()
```

Comment: Se agradece tu contribución pero es importante revises [answer] para realizar una buena respuesta,  si la pregunta esta basada en opiniones o no es muy clara no es de mucha utilidad a otros usuarios. Si es demasiada amplia es difícil tener una respuesta que pueda resolver el problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la verdad es bastante simple, puedes realizar un for para iterar sobre cada elemento de tu base de datos, debes tener en cuenta que libreria usas para manejar la conexion con tu base de datos, en este ejemplo uso `pymysql`:

```
sql1 = "SELECT `nombre` `sexo` `edad` `telefono` FROM elnombre_de_tu_tabla"

cursor.execute(sql1)
all = cursor.fetchall() # Aca asignamos a la variable all el resultado
```

Luego tienes que agregar todos esos valores en tu aplicacion iterando sobre los elementos, por lo general pymysql retorna un diccionario:

```
indice = 1

for item in all:
    hoja['A%s' % indice].value = item['nombre']
    hoja['B%s' % indice].value = item['sexo']
    hoja['C%s' % indice].value = item['edad']
    hoja['D%s' % indice].value = item['telefono']
    indice += 1
```

Tu pregunta es muy amplia pero te dejo esta peque guia, aca te dejo el link de pymysql si estas trabajando con MySQL. Recuerda pasar en el connector la variable `cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor` , para que te retorne diccionario

http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html